# How to solve this non-linear differential equation using the substitution $u = y'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following homogeneous DE:

$y'' + 2y(y')^3 = 0$

So first I let $u = y'$

Therefore $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

If I substitute this back into the equation I get:

$\frac{du}{dx} + 2yu^3 = 0$

My problem is, how do I get rid of this $y$ in the equation to get it in terms of $u$ only?

I tried doing this:

$\frac{du}{dx} + 2y(\frac{dy}{dx})(u^2) = 0$

$\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{2ydy}{dx}u^2 = 0$

That's as far as I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the equation up like this

$$-\frac{y''}{(y')^2} = 2yy' \implies \frac{1}{y'} = y^2 + C_1$$

then multiply both sides by $y'$ and integrate again

$$x + C_2 = \frac{1}{3}y^3 + C_1 y$$

assuming $y' \neq 0$. There is also the constant solution $y(x)=k$ for any real-valued $k$.

---

If you want to use that substitution, start with the equation you ended up with

$$\frac{du}{dx} + 2yu^3 = 0$$

and try to change the derivative to be in terms of $y$ instead of $x$

$$ \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = u\frac{du}{dy}$$

by the chain rule. Then substitute this in to the equation to get

$$\frac{du}{dy} + 2yu^2 = 0$$

again assuming $u$ (really $y'$) is not zero. Then use separation of variables

$$ -\frac{du}{u^2} = 2ydy \implies \frac{1}{u} = y^2 + C_1$$

and the exact same steps apply as in the previous answer.

The other way to do this is to turn it into a nonlinear Integro-DE, which I don't recommend.

Comment: Yes but the question is asking to solve this using the substitution $u = y'$. That's the part im struggling with

Comment: @AndrewKor By question you mean your post or the actual problem statement you got this from?

Comment: Both, since the post has to do with a question in the book

Comment: @AndrewKor I amended my answer to include a solution with the substitution.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution $y' = u$ is, more precisely written, $y' = u(y)$. Plugging this into your equation results in the ODE

$$u'u + 2yu^3 = 0$$

for the function $u = u (y)$, so you don't have to get rid of the $y$ because $y$ is the independent variable now. We have that $u = 0$ is a solution. Otherwise, divide by $u$ and obtain the equation $u' + 2yu^2 = 0$. This equation is separable:

$$\frac{\mathrm du}{u^2} = - 2y\ \mathrm d y.$$

Solve this equation for $u(y)$. In order to get $y$ now, you have to solve

$$\int \frac{\mathrm dy}{u(y)} = \int \mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Hi How did you get $\frac{dy}{u(y)} = dx$  from the previous line?

Comment: Your substitution $y' = u(y)$ is a differential equation. Here, the left hand side $y'$ describes the derivative with respect to $x$, so it can be written as $\mathrm dy/ \mathrm dx = u(y)$. Since you have solved for $u(y)$, you can separate this equation into $\mathrm dy /u(y) = \mathrm dx$ and then integrate in order to obtain $y = y(x)$.

Comment: Your second derivative is not correct, $y''(x)=u'(y)y'(x)=u'u$, the factor $u$ is missing.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is, how do I get rid of this y in the equation to get it in terms of u only?
$$\frac{du}{dx} + 2yu^3 = 0$$
Rewrite it like this
$$\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} + 2yu^3 = 0$$
$$u\frac{du}{dy} + 2yu^3 = 0$$
It's separable.